# Log4Net not working in MVC web application but working in console and window application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I have created a solution which consist of **class library**, **MVC web application** and **console application**.

For my class library project is actually responsible to perform logging using **log4net** which is also included the log4net configuration in the **log4net.config**. Currently i am facing a problem which the logging is not working when my web application call the logging function from class library. But it's working fine when my console application. My log4net.config looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\Temp\" />
      <datePattern value="'Test.log_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%method] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have also included the line below in my **class library** **[AssemblyInfo.cs]**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

My sample class library function as below:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
public void Write ()
{
    log.Info("Success");
}
```

I have set the log4net.config **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always**.

Sample log4net  output from **console application** [**Test.log_yyyy-MM-dd.log**]:

```
2019-10-01 12:07:48,923 [1] INFO  ClassLibrary2.Class1 [Write] - Success
```

But there is log file generated for MVC web application. Is there any additional step need to configure for the web application?

I would be grateful for any help with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add something in your Application_Start method? (global.asax) like:

```
string l4net = Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(l4net));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To Add ConfigSections in your web.config. Also there's the guide especially for MVC applications.

`<configSections> 
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" /> 
</configSections>`

[Complete Guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/how-to-use-log4net-in-mvc-to-track-error/)